# gmail this message was not encrypted

Tags: email, email-server, encryption, tls, gmail

I just moved my site to another hosting provider. I use SSL/TLS for connection security and port 995. It sends my messages but the problem is that gmail shows `This message was not encrypted` red flag.

I contacted hosting provider and they replied that their server uses TLS encryption to transport the emails, but it doesn't encrypt the email itself. They say they can not do anything.

This makes me confused, doesn't mean that using TLS encryption itself automatically encrypt the message? Is there any way to get rid of this red flag?

tnx!

Edit:
This is message header

```
    Delivered-To: er.....@gmail.com
    Received: by 10.25.125.70 with SMTP id y67csp120510lfc;
            Fri, 25 Mar 2016 04:39:05 -0700 (PDT)
    X-Received: by ....83 with SMTP id 80mr38822350wma.76.1458905945860;
            Fri, 25 Mar 2016 04:39:05 -0700 (PDT)
    Return-Path: <...@....com>
    Received: from sip......net ([....153])
            by mx.google.com with ESMTP id g5s......4.39.05
            for <er...@gmail.com>;
            Fri, 25 Mar 2016 04:39:05 -0700 (PDT)
    Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of ...rd.com designates 87.76.19.153 as permitted sender) client-ip=....153;
    Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
           dkim=pass header.i=@....com;
           spf=pass (google.com: domain of ...@....com designates ......153 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=...@....com
    Comment: DomainKeys? See http://domainkeys.sourceforge.net/
    DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws;
      s=default; d=....com;
      b=YHNywjgHFWNR5FmdxEvGk2/8WNw8AgRe+inDncCSKtz09ftSIrQHqdLxzDvR16JW+AP4g784aIUAV7Y6k1arDA6vAkjHZwC8j8rsJLrhmnsroAlNiKg+oHCqPxMHCs8D7+36G53Sdy6nvhM3Jo4NriI+acTNi9/BeMX4U1LgQ8k=;
      h=Received:Received:To:From:Subject:Message-ID:Date:User-Agent:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding;
    DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed; d=....com; h=to:from
        :subject:message-id:date:mime-version:content-type
        :content-transfer-encoding; s=default; bh=H54ykBr5z+w0HlaAcOLIHY
        pgyhk=; b=kLng1/OJTssDS5BDYcgDKuJOfnTOK8sieNSbRyetCGpWCpqjRUdopX
        otwjAPzuLx/aV5JEg6kVf/c7CDC1rV3GaxmieWri0bpmKiHTB+yj1S0glR38RdaD
        AQLE+gV6hofyf5syPp8FXLKe2/gOfpzE0OCedMiEeY6Tho9z01zt0=
    Received: (qmail 33746 invoked by uid 108); 25 Mar 2016 07:39:02 -0400
    Received: from unknown (HELO ?....0.100?) (...@....com@....124)
      by sipuk......net with ESMTPSA; 25 Mar 2016 07:39:02 -0400
    To: ... ... <.......@gmail.com>
    From: ... <...@....com>
    Subject: probavam
    Message-ID: <56F5234C.3010106@....com>
    Date: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 12:38:52 +0100
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101
     Thunderbird/38.7.0
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

se tole probam

Comment: No, it doesn't. They're right.

Comment: Gmail flag only indicates that TLS wasn't used - not that the email lacks encrypted content. Check the email headers, chances are they are not actually using TLS

Comment: Where does TLS appears inside header? I just edited my question and attachment email headers.

Comment: In 'Received:' you would see a line like `(version=TLS1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128);` - The last relay to gmail (`Received: from sip......net by mx.google[...]`) is not using TLS.

Comment: Your provider is full of it. The headers clearly show that they did not use TLS when delivering the message to Gmail.